# how to store current session state for next login of user in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, state, oracle-apex, session-state

I would like to log the process for the current process steps performed.
That means when the user logs in the next time, he can see the current status of the process.
For this I have a column called STATE in the table (which is edited by all participants in the course of the process). This is always set to a different status by a trigger when the table is edited or deleted (like REQUESTED, ACCEPTED,DENIED....).
Now I would like that when a user logs in, it is checked in which status he is in the process and on this basis it can be decided which process step should be displayed to him.

So my question is, how can this be reached? How can I work with states?
I'm not asking for any code here, just a hint if it's possible and in best case some keywords so I can search for the right things to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like that when a user logs in, it is checked in which status he is in the process and on this basis it can be decided **which process step should be displayed to him**.

Where would you display it? To me, it looks as if you'd add the `STATE` column into interactive report or a form or wherever user goes upon login in order to see process status.

Whichever option you choose, at the end it will be a `select` statement of one kind or another, such as

- in interactive report's query,
- source of an item,
- perhaps a stored function which accepts e.g. process ID and returns its status),
- maybe an application item whose value is populated in application computation or process,
- etc.

Comment: Maybe I explain it in other words, the user performs a number of process steps (e.g. filling in forms), and is redirected to the next page after submitting.
Here he has an overview of the entire process (represented as a progress bar). So the next time the user logs in, I want him to be taken directly to the page (that he get displayed when he submitted the forms) and not be taken through the steps again.

Comment: At the same time, the status of the process is always changing because other users are performing steps in this process. This means that this page, the view of the process is always different and must be kept up to date.

Comment: Aha, so each step in that process is performed on a different Apex page. If that's so, create a new table which shows that "step 1 = page 23", "step 2 = page 25" etc. so when user logs in and you find that status is 2, redirect it to page 25. For example, create a button whose label is "Go to the last status" (or next, whichever you prefer). Create URL to the page using APEX_PAGE.GET_URL.

Comment: Ok I created the table with columns like "USERID", "STATE" and "PAGE". As well I created a trigger that fires when a user submits a page, it retrieves the information about the process step (state of process) from the corresponding table and sets the userid and page number automatically (nv('APP_PAGE_ID') . You are saying that when the user logs in you find that status is for example 'REQUESTED' but I do not quite understand how can I find this out?

Comment: One option is to create (in Shared Components) application item (which will hold the status) and be populated by application process.

Comment: I have created the application item STATUS_OF_FORM and as Application Process :select fp.STATE into :STATUS_OF_FORM
     FROM PROCESSSTEPS_FORM fp
     left outer join USERS u
    where u.username=:app_user; but now I am getting an error: that says that no data is found. I try to look at it again

Comment: Letter case? E.g. `where upper(u.username) = :APP_USER`. Besides, you're outer joining two tables, but there's no join condition between them.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I have forgotten to properly join the table and make APP_USER upper case. For the branch for the button ('Go to last Status'). Do I get it right that I have tp choese as behaviour "Function returning a URL(redirect) and insert in the pl/sql function body the function APEX_UTIL_GET_URL() with regards to the application item ?

Comment: I have created this pl/sql function body: declare
v_state =:V('STATE_OF_FORM')
begin
  if v_state in ('REQUESTED')
  then 
SELECT APEX_PAGE.GET_URL (
            p_page   => 80)
         APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL('f?p=104.:80:&APP_SESSION.::::')
     FROM DUAL
     end if;
     end;                                                                                                                               but I am not sure how I can reference the application item

Comment: You'd have to SELECT ... INTO (as it is PL/SQL). That "INTO" would be yet another application item (or a Global Page item) which would then contain target URL.

Comment: I do not quite understand this, does it mean I would need for every process step an application item with the corresponding url. I thought with the table created (that holds the userid, the state and the page of the process), I could then use the application item (State) to check in which state the process is for the specific user, and then redirect him to the specific page (this information I could retrieve from the table?) or did I understood it wrong. I'm sorry for the confusion

Comment: Back to my 1st comment: I'd create a **table** that contains pairs of [status, target page] and - based on what status is, select that particular TARGET_PAGE and navigate to it.

Comment: I tried this pl/sql statement :                                                                                
declare
v_page number;
v_stored_state_in_tbl varchar2(50);
v_state_of_user varchar2(50);

begin

select fp.page, fp.STATE into v_page,v_stored_state_in_tbl   from PROCESSSTEPS_FORM fp where upper(fp.AUDIT_USER)=:APP_USER;

if v_stored_state_in_tbl  = V('STATE_OF_FORM')
THEN 
SELECT APEX_PAGE.GET_URL (
            p_page   => v_page)
            INTO v_page
        
     FROM DUAL;
     end if;
end;

Comment: so meaning that if table stored state equals application item ,then redirect to page which is defined in the table

Comment: Exactly, that was my idea.

Comment: ok thank you very much! then the problem lies in my syntax or in the application process

Comment: You're welcome & good luck, I hope you'll make it work!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231161/discussion-between-gisnow-and-littlefoot).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do could be done pretty simply using **Apex Preference** functionality, where you can save these values as part of their session and retrieve it the next time they connect. No need for your own database table.  I've used this for ages and it works nicely for something simple like this.

Syntax from the manual:

```
APEX_UTIL.SET_PREFERENCE (
    p_preference IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_value IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_user IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL);

APEX_UTIL.GET_PREFERENCE (
    p_preference IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_user IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT V('USER'))
    RETURN VARCHAR2;
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! With this approach, I don't quite understand how I can relate the preference (in this case the page number) to the status of the form. Where do I actually set the preference and where do I get it?

Comment: When your user moves through your process steps, each time they save the page, you could save the last page ID they were on (or whatever you have to track their progress) with SET_PREFERENCE. When they log in the next time, you retrieve that page ID with GET_PREFERENCE and then take them there.